# How to calculate Round Trip Time in Ping utility implementation in UnetStack

Tags: unetstack

I had developed ping utility similar to the ping example available in UnetStack1.3 (`/samples/ping`) to ping a remote node over a multi-hop link, but unable to calculate the Round Trip Time (RTT), when I transmit ping packet using routing agent with static route information added to routing table using `RouteDiscoveryNtf` as there is no timing information avaiable in upper layer notifications (`DatagramNtf` or `DatagramDeliveryNtf` or `DatagramFailureNtf`).

Calculation of round trip time is the difference of `rxtime` and `txtime` available with `TxFrameNtf` and `RxFrameNtf` as implemented in clousure (`fshrc.groovy`) in the ping example.

**I also tried analyzing the ping utility implemented in UnetStack3, but unable to makeout. Please let me know how the RTT is calculated**.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simplified version of the implementation of the `ping` command in UnetStack3:

```
  def ping(int n, int m = 3, long timeout = 30000) {
    println "PING $n"
    AgentID router = agentForService(Services.ROUTING)
    int p = 0
    m.times { count ->
      def t0 = currentTimeMillis()
      router << new DatagramReq(to: n, reliability: true)
      def ntf = receive({
        it instanceof DatagramDeliveryNtf || it instanceof DatagramFailureNtf
      }, timeout)
      def t = currentTimeMillis()-t0
      if (ntf == null || ntf instanceof DatagramFailureNtf) {
        println "Request timeout for seq $count"
      } else {
        p++
        println "Response from $n: seq=$count rthops=2 time=$t ms"
      }
      delay(5000)
    }
    println "$m packets transmitted, $p packets received, ${Math.round(100*(m-p)/m)}% packet loss"
  }
```